# How can I replace or eliminate the InnoSetup 'Are you sure' prompt during uninstall

Tags: inno-setup

I've been asked to customize the 'Are you sure' question asked at the beginning of an uninstall of our product built with InnoSetup 5. Is there a way to replace the text or the entire question with a custom action during uninstall?

Comment: Accepted. Sorry. Totally forgot to come back and look. Didn't know I had gotten an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not modify `Default.isl`, instead just add a `[Messages]` section in your script and specify an override for the `ConfirmUninstall` value there.

Alternatively you can create a new `.isl` file (with only that `[Messages]` section) and specify both it and the original `Default.isl` in your script via the `[Languages]` section.  (You only need to specify the specific messages you want to override; everything else will cascade to the default files.)